# RIA service validation, not update value if invalid

Tags: silverlight, validation, ria

In my Silverlight RIA application, a decimal property need to be validated. I have tried to use RegularExpression and Range to annotate the property in metadata like following:

```
//[RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = "Quantity has to be a positive numeric value")]      
[Range(typeof(decimal), "1", "1000",  ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be between {1} and {2}")]
```

When add new entity, both can validate a numberic value, but if I key in letter, both do not flag any error, but not update the property either. For example, if I type in 2 first, then change to "test", there is no error message on the text box. When Save the entity, the property value still has 2.

Is this expected behavior? If yes, how can I make it to flag any none numeric entry as error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause. Since the property type is decimal, when input text, it will throw an exception and never reach to "Set", so the validation don't get fired. Set "ValidatesOnExceptions=True" on the control will dispay the default error message "Invalid format".

Comment: But I still have issues with this. If I put in letter in the input box, even the exception bring up the error message, the "Save" button still get enabled because no validation error at this point. How to catch this exception and add validation error so Save button can be disabled?